# Why might this Cloud Function not be triggering a notification?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Cloud Function in Firebase that sends a notification to devices with tokens that are stored as documents in a collection:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendDMNotification = functions.firestore.document('/dm_threads/{thread_id}/messages/{message_id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


        const newMessage = snapshot.data();

        const senderName = newMessage.authorName;
        const senderID = newMessage.authorUID;
        const messageText = newMessage.message;
        const recipientName = newMessage.recipientName;
        const recipientID = newMessage.recipientUID;
        const timestamp = newMessage.timestamp;

        console.log(senderName + " " + senderID + " " + messageText + " " + recipientName + " " + recipientID + " " + timestamp.toString());

        let deviceTokenQuery = admin.firestore().collection(`/Users/${recipientID}/device_tokens/`);

        return deviceTokenQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {
            console.log('deviceTokenQuery returned');

            let tokens = querySnapshot.docs;

            console.log('1');


            const notificationPromises = tokens.map(token => {
                console.log('2');

                let token_id = token.tokenID.toString();

                console.log('3');

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: senderName,
                        body: messageText,
                        icon: "default"
                    }
                };


                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)

            });
            console.log('4');
            return Promise.all(notificationPromises);

        });

    });
```

Only "deviceTokenQuery returned", "1", and "4" log statements appear. Do I have a syntax problem or am I not using these these methods properly?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire Cloud Functions code, not just the part that sends a message.  You're likely doing something else wrong.

Comment: I added the index.js file.

Comment: `tokens` is an array of objects describing the contents of the documents matched by the query.  But it looks like your code is assuming it's just an array of strings.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I had to store the tokens as objects instead of strings. The actual string appears as the name of the document and as a child of the object contained therein. I'll have to find a way to get that out. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the fields from the document are all properties on the object.

Comment: Alas, it doesn't seem to be that either. I updated the code with some log statements. It never enters that map of promises. The collection isn't empty.